# Single image is not being saved

Tags: rendering

When I try to render an image operating in from the info menu, it will not make a still render, it seems to render the same still image over and over like an animation not stopping, it renders it then instantly start´s to render again. and it will not render it in the tmp on c: that it usually does, for some odd reason in cycles it render´s a still picture but in blender´s own render not ! 
i have set it to render from frame 1 to 1 but does not help . what could be a reason for this behavior ?

Comment: When you render a still image, you need to manually save the result, only using render animation automatically saves to disk. How many [render layers](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/post_process/layers.html) do you have? A new render is started for each render layer, with each normally having different settings.

Comment: thanks ,this cleared the table, i had downloadet in my scene a foreing model and it had inside it settings that im not used to, and this caused the confusin rendering , but it=s ok now.